# Gitlab Rack Attack Insallation

Tags: ruby, rack, gitlab

I was installing gitlab and followed all the instructions of the installation guide of Gitlab. Everything works fine but then at Step "Initialize Database and Activate Advanced Features"
it failed!

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md

I got this error Message.

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rack::Attack
/home/git/gitlab/config/application.rb:82:in `<class:Application>'
/home/git/gitlab/config/application.rb:13:in `<module:Gitlab>'
/home/git/gitlab/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

In the application.rb file I uncommented the line as it says in the instruction.

```
# Enable rack attack middleware
# Find and uncomment the line 'config.middleware.use Rack::Attack'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, from [issue 5245](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5245):

> Rack Attack is new for 6-2 stable which will be released on 22rd of october.

That being said, read "[`doc/security/rack_attack.md`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/security/rack_attack.md)":

uncomment the line `config.middleware.use Rack::Attack` in the [`config/application.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/application.rb) find **isn't enough**.

The other steps are:

> - Rename [`config/initializers/rack_attack.rb.example`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/initializers/rack_attack.rb.example) to `config/initializers/rack_attack.rb`
> - Review the `paths_to_be_protected` and add any other path you need protecting
> - Restart GitLab instance