# NameError Rack::Attack installing GitLab 7.2

Tags: ruby, rake, bundler, gitlab

I've got a NameError installing GitLab 7.2. More precisely when initializing the database:

```
$ bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production --trace
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Rack::Attack
/home/[user]/gitlab/config/application.rb:67:in `<class:Application>'
/home/[user]/gitlab/config/application.rb:9:in `<module:Gitlab>'
/home/[user]/gitlab/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/[user]/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/[user]/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Yes, I found this [answer discussing the error with an older version of GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391468/gitlab-rack-attack-insallation/19396572#19396572), where the following line in config/application.rb had to be uncommented

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Attack
```

In 7.2. this line is uncommented from the start. It's there. It's apparently where rake chokes.

I renamed config/initializers/rack_attack.rb.example to config/initializers/rack_attack.rb as well.

Installing the bundle gems worked like a charm.

```
bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

rack-attack is in the bundle's gems folder:

```
/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-attack-2.3.0/lib/rack/attack.rb
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem? Thanks a lot!

#### Very ugly workaround™

I added the following line to config/application.rb and it's working:

```
require '/home/[user]/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-attack-2.3.0/lib/rack/attack.rb'
```

Why is this working? What's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't add comment, so I need to post it as an answer: You need to update your ruby & gems: take a look at https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#2-ruby.

> GitLab requires Ruby (MRI) 2.0 or 2.1 You will have to use the
>   standard MRI implementation of Ruby. We love JRuby and Rubinius) but
>   GitLab needs several Gems that have native extensions.